# What is the GwtDocumentBridge mentioned in the realtime drive docs?

Tags: gwt, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

The API docs give a tantalizing hint of GWT bindings for the realtime service, but I can't find other mention of them.

> Parameters:
>   gapi.drive.realtime.GwtDocumentBridge bridge — The driver for the GWT collaborative libraries.

I'm in the process of writing a GWT app with the realtime API and there's a bunch of complex plumbing that would be great to avoid!  Is this `GWT collaborative libraries` reference to something that is already out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but that is just an implementation detail.  There is not a GWT API available at this time, just the javascript one.